# Excel COUNTIFS blank cells within a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I include a 'cell is blank' to a countifs formula.

I've tried `=countifs(<column reference>,"=" & "*")`, which works in standard cells, but does not work within a table (listobject).  All cells return as 'not empty'.

I've created a small sample table and the behavior repeats.

Note, that I do not wish to add VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
'for anything non-blank
=countifs(table1[column], "<>")
'for blank
=countifs(table1[column], "=")
```